# to submit form if value of date is less then current date ? Using NgModel and angular 9

Tags: angular

I need to disable submitting the form if the date is earlier than the current date.

I tried this but it does not work:

Comment: If you want to compare two date, it is better to convert them into time;
this.vehicle.date.getTime() < lastDate.getTime()

Comment: NO work with getTime()

Comment: example is here : https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bootstrap-disabled?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: Using typedef `string | Date | any` is useless, fyi.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare dates.getTime() to disable submit button as shown in code below

```
public disabledDate() {
    const today = new Date();
    today.setDate(today.getDate() - 1);
    return (
        !this.myDateValue ||
        (this.myDateValue && today.getTime() > this.myDateValue.getTime())
    );
}
```

Comment: Have you tried doing this on a stackblitz example? It doesn't work the way I copied the code.

Comment: Yes
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bootstrap-disabled-zzdf8w?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: Yes this work but how to disabled submit form if myDateValue not populated and if todat > of myDateValue

Comment: Yes that is work on stackblitz but in my code i need to update answear because got error myDateValue is string and can't use getTime() with string.

Comment: Don't use empty quotes with type any. Leave it undefined. "myDateValue: any;"

Answer (score 0):

no need to make a method to check one condition, just initialize last date in your .ts like :

```
lastDate: string | Date | any = new Date();
```

and directly put a condition in your .html like :

```
<button [disabled]="myDateValue<lastDate" (click)="submitForm()">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Problem is myDateValue because that is string in my code...

Comment: or else declare myDateValue as a Date